# How to differentiate with dependent variables in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
eqn=x**2+y
print(eqn.diff(x))
```

Getting 2*x but required 2*x+y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have to initialize y as a function of x rather than a Symbol

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
y = Function('y')(x)
eqn = x**2 + y
x=eqn.diff(x)
print(x)
# 2*x + Derivative(y(x), x)
```

[Source:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sympy/manoj%7Csort:date/sympy/igYCciTo0wc/8luhA1JzBQAJ)GUser Jashan

As mention by Smichr(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089161/smichr) ,to get dy/dx from an equation or expression = 0

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
eqn = x**2 + y
x=idiff(eqn,y,x)
print(x)
# -2*x
```

Comment: You might also check out idiff if you are just hoping to solve an equation implicitly for dy/dx. Try `help(idiff)`.